# How do I set the timeout in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, concurrency, timeout, rust-tokio

`rx` get a data from the http listener, and push the data to a `guard`.
When the length of the `guard` is eqaul(or longer than) 3, send it to a new channel.
Not only when the vector length is 3, but also when the vector length is 1(or 2), if more than a few seconds have elapsed, I want to send it to the new channel the same.

Here is my code snippet.

```rust
async fn process_flume1_data(
    rx: Receiver<RequestMessage>,
    tx2: Sender<SessionIdsWithTokens>,
    request_vec: Arc<RwLock<Vec<RequestMessage>>>,
    mut tokenizer: tokenizers::Tokenizer,
) {
   
    while let std::result::Result::Ok(request_message) = rx.recv_async().await {
        println!(
            "Received data from Flume channel1: {:?}",
            request_message.message
        );
        let mut guard = request_vec.write().await;
        guard.push(request_message);
        if guard.len() >= 3
            || tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(3), async {
                let result = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
                    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(4));
                })
                .await;
                result
            })
            .await
            .is_ok()
        {
                // send to new channel...
            }

//...//
```

I tried like this.

```rust
if guard.len() >= 3
            || tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(3), async {
                let result = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
                    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(4));
                })
                .await;
                result
            })
            .await
            .is_ok()
        {
```

not always but somtimes, When the length of `guard` shorter than 3 and was delayed for more than a second, the logic of sending to the new channel did not execute. How can I modify my code?

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: timeout after getting a message is wrong here, because for example in the first 2 seconds, you might get two more messages and then guard>= 3 and you should send the messages immediately. You need to `select` between two futures, one which waits for 3 messages, and another which sleeps for 3 seconds.